# When I add shared_preferences dependency my project doesn't run

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

when I add Shared_Preferences dependency my project doesn't run

Version : last version 2.2.0

This is the error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:classpath'.
Could not find gradle-7.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2).
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of

I added WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() in the main function. When I remove the dependency my problem did get solved, but I need this dependency for set token as string

Comment: What version of gradle is installed?  Does flutter doctor report anything? Tried flutter clean?  Cleared cache and restarted ide?

Comment: My gradle version is : gradle-7.5-all.zip . No flutter doctor command doesn't report anything.  I did clean flutter and cleared cache and restarted ide

Comment: I think this error is only related to Shared_Preferences dependency

Comment: I've used the same shared_preferences dependency and have not run into the error you are.  I suspect there is an issue with gradle on your computer.  You might try editing your question to include the gradle details such as your build.gradle file and also add a gradle tag.

Comment: Sorry Stack Overflow won't let me