# Flutter "Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:parseDebugLocalResources'" failed debug

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, package, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app and when I install the SharedPreferences package (and not even using) and try to debug the application on the chrome, it runs normally, but when I debug it on my device (Samsung Galaxy S10) or on the android studio emulator it throws the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar
```

here is my build.gradle (I fixed the SdkVersion to 34, otherwise it would run at all)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.movie_night"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.movie_night"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and here is my pubsec.yaml dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  uuid: ^3.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.0
  dio: ^5.3.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
```

I already tried to run `flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run`, but doesn't work either.

P.S.: I use windows as SO (don't know if it affects something)

Comment: Sometimes some packages can conflict with other packages and show errors. I fixed myself by exchanging/considering other package versions.

Comment: Try to update your packages.

Comment: @AshikulIslamSawan I already tried updating them with flutter pub upgrade, but still didn't solved :(

Comment: Check pu.dev, your provider package isn't updated. Also, try restarting your IDE.

Comment: Is this the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984394/when-i-add-shared-preferences-dependency-my-project-doesnt-run

Comment: @AshikulIslamSawan I removed the provider package (I wasn't using) and updated all packages, still not working

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it!

Although setting the SDK version to 34, it was searching for the files od SDK version 33, so I went to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34` copied the `android.jar` and pasted it inside `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33`.

When I debugged again, it was working just fine